# Why does regex take too long to evaluate for certain value?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Below is my regex :

```
(https?:\/\/)([a-zA-Z]{2,6}\.)*((?!.*[|!{}[\]^"*;]).)+(\.*)([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\/\:\?&=_%#]+)+([&|?])+$
```

It is to validate a URL with a negative look-ahead to allow characters from other languages.

This is what happens when I test it at http://regex101.com/#javascript:

For -

> http://server.com/path?id=1111111 - NO MATCH
>
> http://server.com/path?id=11111111 - TIMEOUT Your expression took too long to evaluate.
>
> http://server.com/path?id=111111111111111111111& - MATCH

**Observations:**

When the value of the query parameter is increased above certain length it times out.

But for a matching URL the length of parameter value doesn't matter.

Why does it time out for beyond certain length? Which part of regex do I need to modify?

Note: RegEx mandates URL to end with `?` or `&`

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

> What I need is, a regex to validate all standard (for e.g. www.xyz.com
>   or someip:port followed by path parameters and/or query parameters,
>   etc) URLs. It should support characters from other languages as well.
>   With an additional validation to mandate the URL to end with `?` or
>   `&`.

Comment: can you explain what your regex tries to achieve? `negative look-ahead to allow characters from other languages`, i do not see how you are achieving it. parts of your regex expression are blatantly wrong.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi Thanks for your response. Actually it's an existing RegEx that I am updating for my need. `((?!.*[|!{}[\]^"*;]).)+` this part of the RegEx is with negative look-ahead which allows all characters except those inside [].

Comment: `((?!.*[|!{}[\]^"*;]).)+` this is pretty conflicting in itself. aren't the `.*` at the start of the negative lookahead and the `.` following the looahead kind of a contradiction?

Comment: you are kind of saying that `"you do not want any character ahead and still want a character ahead"`

Comment: Also regarding your question on why it is taking a long time. Due to the nature of your expression the regex engine spending to much time to find a match and eventually it time out.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi Ohh.. I interpreted it as match any thing but if it's followed by any of the characters in the [] then fail the match and it seems to be working that way.

Comment: If you could update your question with what you want. You probably will find a answer that fits your requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(…+)+` in `([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\/\:\?&=_%#]+)+` leads to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Removing one of the pluses should help.

Comment: You really have eyes like a Hawk. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This was the best I could come up with:

```
\b([\d\w\.\/\+\-\?\:]*)((ht|f)tp(s|)\:\/\/|[\d\d\d|\d\d]\.[\d\d\d|\d\d]\.|www\.|\.tv|\.ac|\.com|\.edu|\.gov|\.int|\.mil|\.net|\.org|\.biz|\.info|\.name|\.pro|\.museum|\.co)([\d\w\.\/\%\+\-\=\&amp;\?\:\\\&quot;\'\,\|\~\;]*)\b
```

JSFiddle: (I used someone else's demo to test it :)

http://jsfiddle.net/3AE9p/

Ofcourse this is not complete but it is pretty close to would you would want and expect!

Comment: Will have a look at it too. Thanks.